# Symmetry of Green's Functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, greens-function

In the book Introduction to Partial Differential Equations by Folland, he states the claim

> Let $ \Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary $ S$. The Green's function $G$ for $\Omega$ exists and for each $x \in \Omega , G(x, \cdot) \in C^\infty(\overline{\Omega} \backslash \{x\})$.

Then he claims

> $\forall x,y \in \Omega : G(x,y) = G(y,x)$.

He provides the following formal argument:
\begin{align*}
    G(x,y) - G(y,x) &= \int_{\Omega}  G(x,z) \delta(y - z) - G(y,z) \delta(x - z) \mathrm{\,d} z \\
    &= \int_{S}  G(x,z) \partial_{\nu _z} G(y,z)  - G(y,z) \partial_{\nu _z} G(x,z) \mathrm{\,d} \sigma(z) = 0 
\end{align*}
as $ \forall  x \in \Omega : \Delta G(x,\cdot) = \delta (x - \cdot)$ and $ G(x, S) = 0$. A strategy for formalising he suggest is that we can excise small balls of $x,z$ from $\Omega$ and then let their radii shrink to zero.

## Approach

As $ G(x , \cdot)\in C^\infty(\overline{\Omega} \backslash \{x\})$ so $\forall x,y \in \Omega : $
\begin{align*}
       G(x, y) - G(y,x) &= G(x, \cdot) \star \delta (y) - G(y, \cdot) \star \delta (x) \\&= \int_{\Omega}  G(x,z) \delta(y - z)  -G(y,z) \delta(x - z) \mathrm{\,d} z \\
       &=  \int_{\Omega} G(x,z) \Delta G(y,z) - G(y,z) \Delta G(x,z) \\
       &= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{\Omega \backslash B_\varepsilon(x,z)}   G(x,z) \Delta G(y,z) - G(y,z) \Delta G (x,z) \mathrm{\,d}z \\
       &= \int_{\partial \Omega} - \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{\partial B_\varepsilon(x) + \partial B_\varepsilon(z)}    G(x,z) \partial_{\nu _z}   G(y,z) - G(y,z) \partial_{\nu _z} G(x,z) \mathrm{\,d} \sigma(z) \\ 
       &=  0 - \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{\partial B_\varepsilon(x) + \partial B_\varepsilon(y)} G(x,z) \partial_{\nu _z} G(y,z) - G(y,z) \partial_{\nu _z} G(x,z)  \mathrm{\,d} \sigma(z) \\
       &= - \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(x)}  (x - z) \cdot (G(x,z) \nabla_z G(y,z) - G(y,z) \nabla _z G(x,z)) \mathrm{\,d} \sigma(z) \\
       &\phantom{sds} - \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(y)} (y - z) \cdot (G(x,z) \nabla_z G(y,z) - G(y,z) \nabla _z G(x,z)) \mathrm{\,d} \sigma(z)
   \end{align*}
where we have used that $ G(x,\cdot) , G(y,\cdot) \in C^\infty(\overline{\Omega} \backslash \{x,y\})$ so Green's identities are applicable, and $ G(x,\partial \Omega) = G(y, \partial \Omega) = 0$.

Can someone tell me why would the end limit be $0$? The last expression looks like Lebesgue Differentiation, but neither the dimensions are right nor is the integrand well-behaved (could be singular at $\{x,y\}$).

Comment: @whpowell96 The Laplacian. It’s properties are mentioned in the first line after the formal argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this more rigorously, you should avoid all mention of the $\delta$ function, and start with the excised domain $\Omega\backslash B_\epsilon(x, y)$. Here $\Delta G(x, z)=0$ and $\Delta G(y, z)=0$, so we have
\begin{align}
0 &= -\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\Omega\backslash B_\epsilon(x, y)} G(x, z)\Delta G(y, z) - G(y, z)\Delta G(x, z)\, dz\\
&= -\int_{\partial \Omega} 0 + \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\partial B_\epsilon(x)\cup \partial B_\epsilon(y)} G(x, z)\partial_\nu G(y, z) - G(y, z)\partial_\nu G(x, z)\, d\sigma\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\partial B_\epsilon(y)} G(x, z)\partial_\nu N(z-y) \,d\sigma - \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\partial B_\epsilon(x)} G(y, z)\partial_\nu N(z-x) \,d\sigma \\
&= G(x, y) - G(y, x).
\end{align}
Here we are using that $G(x, z)-N(x, z)$ is smooth (see the definition of Green's function), and $N(x, z)=N(x-z)=N(z-x)$ is the Newton potential. In particular,
$$
\int_{\partial B_\epsilon(x)} \partial_\nu N(z-x)\,d\sigma = 1.
$$
Since $x$ is the only singularity of $N(x, z)$, we also have
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\partial B_\epsilon(y)} \partial_\nu N(z-x)\,d\sigma = 0.
$$
It is actually in this sense, we say that $\Delta N(x, z)=\delta_x$. As Folland says, see his proof of (2.8) the mean value theorem, for more details.

Comment: I don't see why I need to avoid using $\delta$ since the integrals are interpreted distributionally in that case. 
But I agree the first equality holds trivially as $G(x , \cdot) $ is harmonic away from $x$.

Comment: Actually can you justify why the fourth equality hold?

Comment: The fourth equality holds by the property stated below (let me take $x=0$ for simplicity): $\int_{\partial B_\epsilon(0)} \partial_\nu N(z)\, d\sigma=1$. This follows from the definition of $N(z) = \frac{r^{2-n}}{(2-n)\omega_n}$, $r=|z|$, so $\partial_\nu N(z) = \frac{r^{1-n}}{\omega_n}$. Therefore its integral over $\partial B_r(0)$ is 1, for any $r>0$. The other factor $G(y, z)\to G(y, x)$ on $\partial B_\epsilon(x)$, as $\epsilon\to 0$. (I am talking about the second term here.)

Comment: Now back to your first question. If you want to use the $\delta$ function, then you don't need excisions, and you calculation should continue as $\int_\Omega G(x, z)\Delta G(y, z) - G(y, z)\Delta G(x, z)\,dz=\int_{\partial \Omega} G(x, z)\partial_\nu G(y, z) - G(y, z)\partial_\nu G(x, z)\,d\sigma = 0$. Then that is the zero you were looking for. In this more general sense, $\Delta G = \delta$ so there is nothing more to be done in the inside.

Comment: I have 
\begin{align*}
       &  \int_{\partial B_\varepsilon(x) \cup \partial B_\varepsilon(y)}   G(x, z) \partial_{\nu _z} G(y, z) - G(y, z)  \partial_{\nu _z}G(x,z) \mathrm{\,d} \sigma(z) \\
       &= - \frac{1}{\varepsilon  \lvert  \partial B  \rvert} \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(x)}   G(x, z)\lvert y - z \rvert^{-n} (z-y) \cdot (z - x) - G(y, z) \varepsilon ^{2 - n } \\
       &\phantom{=}- \frac{1}{\varepsilon  \lvert  \partial B \rvert} \int_{\partial  B_\varepsilon(y)}  G(x, z) \varepsilon ^{2 -n}  - G(y, z)  \lvert  x - z \rvert^{-n} (z -y) \cdot (z - x).
   \end{align*}

Comment: So I am unsure how you are able to just use the value of the integral and the convergence property to reduce these down to G(x,y) - G(y,x). 


Secondly, I don't think the result directly follows in distributional setting (as Folland notes that the calculation holds only formally) as the Green's identities are needed, and the validity of those are stated only in classical setting. We can still apply the identities away from \(x, y\) as then the functionals are classical which is why he suggested to excise the balls out.

Comment: Actually the last term equal
   \begin{align*}
      &= - \frac{\varepsilon ^{n-1}}{  \lvert  \partial B \rvert} \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(x)}  G(x, z)  \lvert  y - z \rvert^{-n} (z - y) \cdot \theta +  \frac{1}{ \lvert  \partial B_\varepsilon \rvert} \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(x)}  G(y, z)  \\ 
      &\phantom{=}  +  \frac{\varepsilon ^{n-1}}{ \lvert  \partial  B \rvert}  \int_{ \partial  B_\varepsilon(y)}  G(y,z)  \lvert  x - z \rvert^{-n} \theta \cdot (z - x) - \frac{1}{ \lvert  \partial B_\varepsilon \rvert} \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(y)}  G(x, z)
   \end{align*}

Comment: OK, I see you are on some good point, but the conclusion still holds. Let me call your four terms by $I_1, I_2, I_3, I_4$ in the order. So $I_1\to 0$ and $I_3\to 0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$. Let me show it for $I_1$. $|y-z|\to |y-x|\neq 0$, $G(x, z)\to G(x, x)$ and its order of singularity is that of $N$, so $\epsilon^{2-n}$. Then the term 
 $\epsilon^{n-1}$ brings the whole thing to 0. Similarly for $I_3$. Now $I_2\to G(y, x)$ as $z\to x$, and $I_4\to -G(x, y)$ by the same reason.

Comment: Ahh right, thanks. I forgot we had the formulas for G and I know for n > 2 : G(x,0) ~ |x|²⁻ⁿ. Finally, for the remaining two, we know that G(x,z) is harmonic away from x so we have the mean-value formula.

Comment: I see. $I_2$ and $I_4$ don't even need continuity. You are right, it is true on the nose by the mean value property.

Answer (score 1):

With discussion with @Three aggies, here is the complete solution:

Fix $x \neq y \in \Omega$ and let $ G^x := G(x, \cdot)$. Since $ \Delta G^x = \delta _x$ so $G^x$ is harmonic away from $x.$
When $ n > 2 $, we have $ \partial_{\nu _z} G^x$ on $\partial B_\varepsilon(x)$ is given by
$$  \nu _x (z) \cdot \nabla _z G^x  = \varepsilon ^{-1} (z - x) \cdot \nabla_z \frac{ \lvert  z -x \rvert^{2 - n}}{\omega _n (2 - n)} = (\varepsilon \omega _n ) ^{-1}  \lvert z - x \rvert^2  \lvert z - x \rvert^{ -n} = \varepsilon ^{1 - n} \omega _n ^{-1} =  \lvert  \partial B_\varepsilon \rvert^{-1}
   $$
Moreover, for $ \partial_{\nu _z}G^y$ on $\partial B_\varepsilon(x)$, we have
$$   \lvert  \nu _x(z) \cdot \nabla_z G^y \rvert  = (\varepsilon \omega _n)^{-1}  \lvert  y - z  \rvert^{-n}  \lvert  (z -y) \cdot ( z- x) \rvert  \leq (\varepsilon \omega _n)^{-1}  \lvert y - z \rvert^{1 -n}  \lvert  z- x \rvert. 
   $$
As such, via Green's identities applicable due to smoothness of $G^x$ (respectively $G^y$), away from $x$ and $ G^x(\partial \Omega) = 0$,
\begin{align*}
       0 &= G^x(y)\mathbf{1}_{y \not \in B_\varepsilon(x,y)}  - G^y(x) \mathbf{1}_{x \not \in B_\varepsilon(x,y)} =   \int_{ \Omega \backslash B_\varepsilon(x,y)}  G^x \Delta G^y - G^y \Delta G^x \\
       &= \int_{ \partial \Omega} - \int_{\partial B_\varepsilon(x) \cup \partial B_\varepsilon(y)}   G^x \partial_z G^y - G^y \partial _z G^x \\
      &= - \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(x)}  G^x \partial_{\nu _z} G^y -  \lvert  \partial B_\varepsilon \rvert^{-1} G^y    - \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(y)} \lvert  \partial B_\varepsilon \rvert^{-1} G^x    - G^y \partial _{\nu _z} G^x  \\
      &= - \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(x)} G^x \partial_{\nu _z} G^y  + \frac{1}{ \lvert \partial B_\varepsilon \rvert} \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(x)}  G^y   + \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(y)}  G^y \partial _{\nu _z} G^x  - \frac{1}{ \lvert  \partial B_\varepsilon \rvert} \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(y)}  G^x. 
   \end{align*}
Finally,
$$  \left\lvert  \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(x)}G^x \partial_{\nu _z} G^y  \right\rvert \leq C \varepsilon ^{-1} \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(x)}     \lvert  x -z \rvert^{2 - n}   \lvert y - z \rvert^{1 - n}  \lvert  z - x \rvert \leq C \varepsilon ^{-1} \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(x)}  \varepsilon ^{3 - n}    \lvert y - \frac{x}{2} \rvert^{1 - n} \leq C \varepsilon ^{2 -n + n-1} = C \varepsilon, 
   $$
and $ \frac{1}{ \lvert  B_\varepsilon \rvert} \int_{ \partial B_\varepsilon(x)} G^y  = G^y(x) $ via mean-value formula as $G^y $ is harmonic away from $x$, gives us
$$  0 =  - C \varepsilon + G^y(x)  + C' \varepsilon  - G^x(y). 
   $$
Letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ gives our result.